# Why isdigit is working but isdecimal is not for a simple age code

Tags: python-2.7

This is the part of code I am talking about:

```
while True:
    print 'What is your age(only numeric):'
    age = raw_input()
    if age.isdigit():
        break
    print 'Please try again. We take only numeric value.'
```

When I replace isdigit with isdecimal, I get this error no matter what value i enter.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    if age.isdecimal():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isdecimal'
```

Although it runs fine with isdigit.

Also, when I replace raw_input with input, it give this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    if age.isdigit():
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

Am I doing something wrong which I am not able to catch? I am new to python and did my research about isdigit, is decimal, input and raw_input before putting down question here. It may be very minute error but I am not sure what is it.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part:

In Python 2, `isdecimal` is a method of the `unicode` class, not of `str` (i.e. `bytes`). Hence:

```
>>> '3.2'.isdecimal()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isdecimal'
>>> u'3.2'.isdecimal()
```

For the second part, `input` tries to guess what kind of input it gets, and will properly cast `"1"` into an `int`, while `raw_input` will always return the raw string. Since `isdigit` is a method defined in the `str` class, you get the error.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the detail.